# automatic web crawler

Tags: json, web-crawler

I'm writing a crawler which needs to get data from many websites. The problem is that every website has different structure. How can I easily write a crawler which downloads (correctly) data from (many) different websites? If the structure of a website will change will I need to rewrite the crawler, or are there other methods?

What logical and implemented tools can be used to improve the quality of data mined by an automatic web-crawler (many websites are involved with different structure)?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to query it is some way, in which case you should store the data in a flexible data store. A relational database would not be fit for purpose as it has a strict schema, but something like [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) which lets you store semi structured data without having to define a schema up front, but still provides a powerful query language.

The same goes for how you represent the data in the crawler code. Don't map the data to classes where the structure is defined up front, but use a flexible data structures that can change at runtime. If you are using Java then de-serialise the data into HashMaps. In other languages this might be called Dictionaries or Hashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're scraping data from websites that actually want to allow you to do that, chances are they will provide some sort of webservice to allow you to query their data in a structured way.

Otherwise, you're on your own, and you might even be violating their terms of use.

Answer (score 0):

If the websites provide no APIs, then you're out cold and you have to write separate extraction module for each data format you're encountering. If the website changes the format, then you have to update your format module. A standard thing to do is to have plugins for every website you're crawling and have a testing framework which does regression testing with data you've already collected. When a test fails you know something went wrong and you can investigate whether you have to update your format plugin or if there is another issue.

Without knowing what kind of data you're collecting it will be very difficult to try to hypothesize about ways to improve the "quality" of the data that was mined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could find out whether the website allows you to access the data like API, if so, you could use this kind of structured data to your website directly. If not, you may need plugins for that. Or you could turn to other web crawlers with API access like [Octoparse](http://www.octoparse.com/), to find the way to access their API to your own web crawler.